# Print space if the rows are the same in awk

Tags: bash, awk, uniq

I would like to print space or dot if my rows are the same.

See the example:

INPUT:

```
row1 xx yy zz
row1 xx yy zz
row1 xx yy zz
row2 aa bb cc
row2 aa bb cc
row3 gg hh oo
```

OUTPUT:

```
row1 xx yy zz
     xx yy zz
     xx yy zz
row2 aa bb cc
     aa bb cc 
row3 gg hh oo
```

Is there any easy way to print just space?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ awk '{c=$1} c==p{gsub(/./," ",$1)} {p=c} 1' file
row1 xx yy zz
     xx yy zz
     xx yy zz
row2 aa bb cc
     aa bb cc
row3 gg hh oo
```

Comment: thats great solution! Thank you so much!

Comment: Ed, can you explain the command please? Also If you wanted tabs rather than spaces, where would they go in this command?

Comment: @Kg123 p is for previous and c is for current. THINK about it and I'm sure you can figure out what it's doing but if you have any specific question about it let me know. wrt your question about tabs - where do you WANT them to go?